# Writing program that computes sum of quiz scores - lists

Tags: python

I have this problem I'm working on:

**Problem:** A final quiz score is computed by adding all the scores, except for the lowest two. Write a program that prints the final score, by making use of lists.

**Attempt:** I think I have everything correct, except I'm not really sure what code I should write under the 'main' function. Here is my code:

```
def main():
    scores = readFloats(values)
    removeMinimum(scores)
    removeMinimum(scores)
    total = sum(scores)
    print("The final score is", total)


def readFloats(values):
    values = []
    userInput = input("Please enter a value or Q to quit: ")
    while userInput != "Q":
        n = float(userInput)
        values.append(n)
        userInput = input("Please enter a value or Q to quit: ")

    return values

def removeMinimum(values):
    smallest = values[0]
    for i in range(len(values)):
        if values[i] < smallest:
            smallest = values[i]

    values.remove(smallest)

main()
```

When I try to run this program, it says the name 'values' is not defined in the 'main' function. I'm not sure how to get the reference correct. The user should be prompted for values, and if the entered values are 8, 4, 7, 8.5, 9.5, 7, 5, 10, the output should be 50. Could someone tell me where my mistakes are?

Comment: in addition to answers below, why are you re-declaring values in readfloats method...so 1) declare values = list() in main, and 2) remove values = [] in readFloats as it overrides the values method passed in via parameter

Comment: You define some functions. You call `main`. `main` begins. `main` looks for `values` and has no idea what that is because it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to the fact that you are using the name `values` in your first call to function `readFloats(values)` while not having supplied an actual value for `values`.

Since the user inputs values using the `readFloats` function, you really don't need to pass a parameter to it. Removing the parameter `values` from `readFloats` will make it execute correctly:

```
# empty parameter list
def readFloats():
    # body of readFloats()
```

Additionally, take note that Python comes with a set of [`built-in`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html) functions that are really useful in contexts like these. Functions like `min()` and `max()` will come in handy.

Comment: Thanks, that was very clear. So I should never insert a parameter variable in the function when I prompt the user for inputs?

Comment: The way you have implemented the specific function makes the additional parameter unecessary. You declare a list in the function (`values = []`) to hold the values, so you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can instantiate a variable by putting something into it: you haven't done that. You are passing something called 'values' to the readFloats method but you haven't put anything in it, therefore the variable does not exist and Python can't find it. In the main put something into 'values' before passing it to readFloats. Tell Python it's an array of floats.

Answer (score 1):

> @Dimitris Jim:  (It's very good explanation thats why I use it)
>   Your error is due to the fact that you are using the
>   name values in your first call to function readFloats(values) while
>   not having supplied an actual value for values.
>
> Since the user inputs values using the readFloats function, you really
>   don't need to pass a parameter to it. Removing the parameter values
>   from readFloats will make it execute correctly:

Just simply you can do it by [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
>>> score = [8, 4, 7, 8.5, 9.5, 7, 5, 10]
>>> score.sort()
>>> score
[4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8.5, 9.5, 10]
>>> sum(score[2:])
50.0
>>>
```

According to your code:

```
def main():
    scores = readFloats()
    scores.sort()
    print("The final score is", sum(scores[2:]))


def readFloats():
    values = []
    userInput = raw_input("Please enter a value or Q to quit: ")
    while userInput != "Q":
        n = float(userInput)
        values.append(n)
        userInput = raw_input("Please enter a value or Q to quit: ")

    return values

main()
```

Output:

```
Please enter a value or Q to quit: 4
Please enter a value or Q to quit: 8
Please enter a value or Q to quit: 7
Please enter a value or Q to quit: 8.5
Please enter a value or Q to quit: 9.5
Please enter a value or Q to quit: 7
Please enter a value or Q to quit: 5
Please enter a value or Q to quit: 10
Please enter a value or Q to quit: Q
('The final score is', 50.0)
```

Comment: What about  `sum(sorted(score)[2:])` ?

Comment: @danihp: it list comprehension. It slice sorted list from index 2 to last value then sum their